# Removing an element from inside a list in python

Tags: python, list

I am a beginner in python. I am trying to convert RLE compressed data into an ASCII image. I have made an algorithm which converts one part of an RLE into ASCII (For example `02a = aa`) to tackle the issue of having a longer line of RLE (For example `02a03b`). I want my program to remove three parts of an array at the time until there is only 3 elements left, so I can run the algorithm one last time and make a part of an ASCII image. The problem is I cannot remove specific parts of an array from inside an element. For example making `['aab']` into `['aa']`.

I have already tried `array.remove`, and `array.pop`, but I get an error message saying

> "ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list"

when the element is clearly there as I print it before hand. I have also tried `del(array[element])` but I get the message

> "TypeError: 'str' object doesn't support item deletion"

```
array1.remove(array1[0][5])
array1.remove(array1[0][4])
array1.remove(array1[0][3])
```

I expect the output to be RLE data converted to ASCII line by line, but I cannot remove the correct part of the array to do so.

Comment: can you post the `array1`.

Comment: `del array[0][5]`